# How to setup SFML on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022 and CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-10, sfml, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to figure out how to get SFML to work with CMake and Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10.

So far I have

- Downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022
- Downloaded a zip file containing what I believe to be the SFML libs and headers which I need to include/link against
- Compiled a hello world program with VS2022

There is a file in my sfml folder `SFMLConfig.cmake`. I need to use this in combination with `find_package` (cmake) but I have no idea how to do this.

- I don't understand where I am supposed to put the SFML folder which I downloaded. I have put it in the root directory of my project (or at least one level lower) it seems like the root is just a place for the first CMakeLists.txt file to live, which just calls `add_subdirectory`.

I've added a screenshot of VS and the sfml folder containing the `.cmake` files.

The sfml folder is structured something like this - if you've used SFML before you are probably familiar with it.

```
sfml/
  bin/
    openal32.dll
    ...
  include/
    sfml/
      Audio/
      Graphics/
      ...
  lib/
    cmake/
      SFML/
        SFMLConfig.cmake
        ...
    sfml-audio.lib
    sfml-audio-d.lib
    ...
  share/
```

[image: sfml]
[image: Visual Studio 2022]

Comment: I've no idea, but in general understand that there is no particular place you must put SFML, nor even any place where it is preferable to put SFML. The whole idea of these configuration options it that you put SFML wherever you like and then tell your other tools where you put it.

Comment: The concept of where you are supposed to put libraries does not really exist on windows unlike linix where it has specific folders. As a result of that in many cases in CMake you have to help it find your installed packages at configure time either by setting command line options, environment variables, set options in the json file ... I don't usually put external libraries in my project I have them in a hierarchy a few levels above the root of my project.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `SFML_ROOT` to `X:\REDACTED\source\repos\REDACTED\REDACTED\sfml`. It is not appropriate to hard-code such a path in the CMakeLists.txt, but you can put it in a [preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html). This works either as a CMake variable or as an environment variable.

Please read the full documentation for `find_package`, the Config-Mode Search Procedure in particular: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Also worth noting: it is *much* easier to manage dependencies on Windows using [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io) than littering dubious ("what I believe to be") binaries across your filesystem.

Comment: vcpkg looks like it would be useful to install. But I need to clone it with git. The VS2022 command prompt apparently doesn't know what `git` is. What should I do? I have absolutly no idea how to install git on windows. On Linux it's 1 line in the terminal

Comment: install tortoise git + git or just the github desktop application.

Comment: No luck with this. Trying to run the bootstrap script fails: The process just dies and prints "Telemetry" and nothing else

Comment: There is help at vcpkg github wiki for that.